# CanJS Model findAll returns list of duplicate items

Tags: javascript, canjs, canjs-model

I'm using `can.Model` to retrieve data by `id`:

```
Invoice = can.Model({
    findAll: 'GET /invoices',
    create  : "POST /invoices",
    update  : "PUT /invoices/{id}",
    destroy : "DELETE /invoices/{id}"
},{});
```

When navigating to `/invoices`, the result is as expected, like:

```
[
    0: {
         "ID": "1",
         "Client": "Client1",
    },
    1: {
         "ID": "2",
         "Client": "Client2"
    }
]
```

However, the data retrieved with `Invoice.findAll` and logged to the console, it looks like this, with the same data item repeated for each element in the list:

```
[
    0: {
         "ID": "1",
         "Client": "Client1"
    },
    1: {
         "ID": "1",
         "Client": "Client1"
    }
]
```

The response from the server is correct, so why is it being interpreted as a list of identical items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When data has an id field different from `id`, it should be specified using the `id` field.  For instance, as mentioned in the [documentation for `can.Model`](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.id.html) in `.NET` it is common to use `Id`. In this case, the id field must be defined as `ID`:

```
Invoice = can.Model({
    id: 'ID',
    findAll: 'GET /invoices',
    create  : "POST /invoices",
    update  : "PUT /invoices/{id}",
    destroy : "DELETE /invoices/{id}"
},{});
```