# CanJs Model Service Method Implementations

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, canjs, canjs-model

I am having trouble understanding how to correctly implement the can.Model service methods. I currently have this

```
var Foo = can.Model({
findAll: "GET /service/Editor.svc/foo",
findOne: "GET /service/Editor.svc/foo/{id}",
create: 'POST /service/Editor.svc/foo"',
update: 'PUT /service/Editor.svc/foo"{id}',
destroy: 'DELETE /service/Editor.svc/foo"{id}'
},{});
```

I have looked at http://canjs.com/guides/Models.html and http://canjs.com/guides/Tutorial.html and [CanJS Model findAll returns list of duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212784/canjs-response-from-model-findall-method-is-same-for-all-rows)

I guess what I don't understand is how the model works. Is the only thing I need for these methods the above declaration? when I try to run

`var test = new Foo()`
then `foo.findAll({}, function(success){//dosomething}, function(xhr){//do something else})`
I get `TypeError: Object #<Constructor> has no method 'findAll'`

What part of this framework am I missing?

For the record this interacts with a c# wcf service and which pulls json objects from a mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `findAll` etc. methods you are defining are constructor methods not prototype methods. That means that you have to call it on the `Foo` object and not the `foo` instance (I usually name my Model and instances of it differently as not to confuse them - e.g. `var bar = new Foo()`).

```
Foo.findAll({}, function(data) {

});

// Or a little nicer:
Foo.findAll({}).then(function(data) {

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. So these are the equivalent of static methods?